# Nativescript ios State Preservation and Restoration

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

Is there a way to setup State Preservation and Restoration for ios using CoreBluetooth in Nativescript?
I'm using the [nativescript-bluetooth plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-bluetooth).

From what I understand I will have to modify the actual plugin's code to be able to implement State Preservation and Restoration based on what I see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW5)

I want to be able to reconnect to a BLE device in case my app is suspended while in background.  Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Refer the [plugin development docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins), you may fork the plugin repo and build your own version over it. Also you must be familiar with [Marshalling iOS native code to JS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview)

Comment: @Manoj thanks there is a beta version of nativescript-bluetooth apparently that handles the case